# Github, why changes don't appear

Tags: git, github

I modified the code of a repository and added some new files, but only the new files appear on Github, the modification doesn't, can anyone tell me why? I did the command `git push origin master`, is there any more commands I need to do?
BTW: `I'm not the master`.

Comment: What is the name of the branch that you are expecting? Did you commit the changed files?

Comment: `master` isn't the name of a role, it's the name of a `branch`. See `man git-branch`

Comment: @Leigh I committed, I'm just wondering only after the modification been accepted, it will appear, is this right?

Comment: @maček The name of the `branch` is `master`, I used `git branch`, only `* master` appears.

Comment: Can you run `git status` and see if the files you changed were actually committed?

Comment: @Leigh Yes, I got the result `modified: ......` which was the file I modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see "nothing to commit" when running `git status` then you haven't yet committed the changes. Those modified files are still just on that computer.

What you need to do is `git add <file that was changed>`, `git commit`, and *then* run the `git push origin master`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `git status` to see your changes. Commit your changes with `git commit -m "my changes"` and at least push your changes to the repository `git push origin yourworkingrepository`.

Comment: Push syntax is `git push <remote> <branch>` not `git push origin <remote>`.

Comment: @Leigh with `git push <remote> <branch>` I got the result `Everything up-to-date`